# Get value of input field and set aria-valuenow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I got a hidden input field on my page which contains a value. I am trying to figure out how to pass that specific value into my slider so the value from input field is the same as aria-valuenow on page load.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input name="input_50" id="input_14_50" type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" aria-invalid="false" value="3500">


<div class="noUi-handle noUi-handle-lower" data-handle="0" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-orientation="horizontal" aria-valuemin="0.0" aria-valuemax="1000000.0" aria-valuenow="500000.0" aria-valuetext="500000"><div class="noUi-touch-area"></div><div class="noUi-tooltip">500.000</div></div>
```

I am trying to make this work using Javascript but doesn't seem to work at all:

```
function setSlidervalue() {
  document.getElementById('input_14_50').value = document.getElementByClassName('noUi-handle-lower').attr('aria-valuenow');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mistake in your JavaScript
For getting the elements by class name you have to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("noUi-handle-lower");
```

So if this is the first element having classname `noUi-handle-lower` then your code will be.

```
document.getElementById('input_14_50').value =   document.getElementsByClassName("noUi-handle-lower")[0].getAttribute('aria-valuenow');
```

here [0] means the first element and so on.
Using only JavaScript